# "username" is not in the sudoer list - how do I get back in there

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, permissions, sudo

I use Ubuntu 9.10
I changed my password. After I restarted my machine and tried to do `sudo whatever...`
I got

> "username" is not in the sudoer list.

What should I do to get back in there?

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu, you need to be in the `admin` group. If you have left the admin group, then try booting to the recovery console:

- when booting, hold down the shift key to bring up the grub menu
- select the second option (which should say "recovery mode" or "recovery console" at the end of the line)
- then add your user to the admin group again

```
# usermod -a -G admin your username
```

- then reboot again and you should be able to do sudo stuff again.

Comment: almost worked for me, I needed to regenrate the root password, as my user has no privileges on the group file. The rest of it, as you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the `/etc/sudoers` file.

It is worth it to note that you will have to be root in order to read / edit the file. See [visudo](http://linux.die.net/man/8/visudo).

Comment: :-) I can't access it, as I don't have `sudo` ...